# Constraints on a Haskell typeclass for the definition of a group

Tags: haskell, math

I came up with this typeclass definition for a [Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition), but I found a counterexample type that is not actually a group.

Here is the class definition and an instance that is the group ℤ₂:

```
class Group g where
  iden :: g
  op :: g -> g -> g
  inv :: g -> g

data Z2T = Z0 | Z1

instance Group Z2T where
  iden = Z0
  Z0 `op` Z0 = Z0
  Z0 `op` Z1 = Z1
  Z1 `op` Z0 = Z1
  Z1 `op` Z1 = Z0
  inv Z0 = Z1
  inv Z1 = Z0
```

However, those type signatures for `Group` are necessary, but not sufficient for a type to really be a group, here's my counterexample that compiles:

```
data NotAGroup = N0 | N1

instance Group NotAGroup where
  iden = N0
  N0 `op` N0 = N0
  N1 `op` N0 = N0
  N0 `op` N1 = N0
  N1 `op` N1 = N0
  inv N0 = N0
  inv N1 = N0
```

How can I encode the sufficient rules for a type to be a group in the `Group` typeclass in Haskell?

Comment: That would require dependent types (found e.g. in Agda but not present in Haskell) or some Hasochistic type-level hackery. Both would not be terribly convenient, since they would force _you_ to provide a proof of the "groupiness" of each instance you define. The compiler would not fill the proof obligation for you (albeit in the finite cases some Template Haskell might produce such a proof for you).

Comment: You can't.  Sorry.

Comment: You might want to look into Coq for this. It is a dependently typed programming language that is also designed to assert and prove theorems about programs. It's overall design is somewhat similar to an "extended" Haskell with a bit different syntax. Here is how I might start in Coq (I have also proven here that your counterexample is indeed not a group): https://gist.github.com/roboguy13/8f52a2cdbac3f37ed31fe9662cf088e1 . Coq also comes with a tool that extracts Haskell code from verified Coq code (so you can verify it in Coq then generate the Haskell version of the correct code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot enforce such laws, but you can document them. The `Monoid` class, for example, documents four laws that any instance of `Monoid` is expected to adhere to:

```
-- | The class of monoids (types with an associative binary operation that
-- has an identity).  Instances should satisfy the following laws:
--
--  * @mappend mempty x = x@
--
--  * @mappend x mempty = x@
--
--  * @mappend x (mappend y z) = mappend (mappend x y) z@
--
--  * @mconcat = 'foldr' mappend mempty@
```

A group is just a monoid with an additional inverse operation. Make your `Group` class a subclass of `Monoid`; then you only need to document the additional law that your inverse operation must obey.

```
class Monoid g => Group g where
  ginverse :: g -> g
  -- ginv must obey the following laws
  -- x `gappend` (ginverse x) == gempty
  -- (ginverse x) `gappend` x == gempty

-- g-prefixed synonym for mappend
gappend :: Group g => g -> g -> g
gappend = mappend

-- g-prefixed synonym for mempty
gempty :: Group g => g
gempty = mempty
```

Comment: Whats the harm in moving `gappend` outside of the typeclass by using the `Group g` constraint and setting `gappend = mappend`? That way it's not overridable but behaves like `mappend`.

Comment: None that I can see :)

Answer (score 6):

You are right that it is possible to write instances of the `Group` typeclass which violates the group laws, because in fact there's nothing in the code actually stating them.

This happens the same way for instance for the `Monad` class, where the monadic laws are not written nor enforced in any way. You can write an unlawful `Monad` instance, as you can write an unlawful `Group` instance.

This is actually the best you can get in Haskell, at least without increasing the complexity of the type signature too much. In fact, to express the group laws in the type you will probably need a fully dependently typed language, which Haskell is not.

In cases like this, laws are usually written in comments, maybe stated as rewrite rules, and programmers are usually disciplinate enough to respect them.